# Enterprise Architect, sequence diagram: alternative return paths

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I'm creating a sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect (Sparx Systems) where there may be several return paths. But on the first return the lifeline is cut off. Is there any solution?
[image: Sequence diagram]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click at the right side of the top left return message and check `Extend...Down`

[image]

This will result in

[image]

To also extend the left lifeline you need to do the same with the message top left.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

It's just a shame that the left lifeline remains discontinuous. Enterprise Architect probably doesn't support it.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your time.